# Highcharts columnrange remove spacing from data in other categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How would I get rid of the 'invisible' spacing as indicated in the picture?

I intend to use the chart in inverted mode (as a gantt chart), but this shows the gaps more obvious. To be able to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/j03ceom5/

I consired an 'xrange' type but it has the same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/agxu6ffc/

[image]

-inserting some code snippet to get the jsfiddle links accepted, eventhough it's not necessarily needed to understand the question-

```
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted:false,
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use workaround which justify columns redraw / load chart event.

```
var justifyColumns = function (chart) {
    var categoriesWidth = chart.plotSizeX / (1 + chart.xAxis[0].max - chart.xAxis[0].min),
        distanceBetweenColumns = 0,
        each = Highcharts.each,
        sum, categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories,
        number;
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        each(chart.series, function (p, k) {
            if (p.visible) {
                each(p.data, function (ob, j) {
                    if (ob.category == categories[i]) {
                        sum++;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        distanceBetweenColumns = categoriesWidth / (sum + 1);
        number = 1;
        each(chart.series, function (p, k) {
            if (p.visible) {
                each(p.data, function (ob, j) {
                    if (ob.category == categories[i]) {
                        ob.graphic.element.x.baseVal.value = i * categoriesWidth + distanceBetweenColumns * number - ob.pointWidth / 2;
                        number++;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmktekak/14/

Comment: That not quite what I was looking for. I'll admit it looks nicer, but the space is still there http://jsfiddle.net/L3ttppy1/ . I'd like the space to be removed and the category therefore condensed.

Comment: At this moment in the Highcharts you can use only this workaround.